# Mysql group by first table date and count distinct field from second table

Tags: mysql

I have `users` table

```
id | email           | website
1    test@gmail.com     google.com
2    blah@hotmail.com   google.com
3    fred@outlook.com   yahoo.com
4    jeff@gmail.com     yahoo.com
```

And a `groups` table

```
id | group     | user_id | created
1    group1       1         2018-06-06
2    group2       2         2018-06-06
3    group3       3         2018-09-09
4    group4       4         2018-06-06
```

I need to get a count of each `website` for each `created` day, so the above would give me **2** for **google.com** on **2018-06-06**

Ie,

```
website   | count   | date

google.com    2        2018-06-06
yahoo.com     1        2018-06-06
yahoo.com     1        2018-09-09
```

I have the rows coming back grouped by date, but the count is all `1` for each row using the following query

```
select count(distinct users.website), groups.created 
from user_groups as groups
 join users on users.id = groups.user_id
 group by groups.created
```

So i'm getting simply

```
count(distinct users.website)  |   created
 1                                  2018-06-06
 1                                  2018-06-06
 1                                  2018-06-06
 1                                  2018-09-09
```

Comment: remove distinct in count. it will remove all duplicates - so if google.com comes multiple times, it will still be counted as one only

Comment: Or,  you can use `count (distinct users.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=471ddc5ab4fce40044a3ba911961b1dd)

```
select website,created,count(website) as cnt
from groups t2 join users t1 on t1.id = t2.userid
group by website, created
```

Comment: @yoyoma, modified the answer with a demo - you can check now

Comment: I think, he is having problem with his data, the query he made don't even match with the result set of his output, I have tested that. Maybe he have to give a try to `GROUP BY TRIM(website), TRIM(created)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Select distinct(groups.created),count(distinct(users.website))
from user_groups as groups
join users on users.id = groups.user_id
group by groups.created
```

Should work.

Comment: also just giving me all count = 1 :(